# Call Javascript/Jquery from Razor?

Tags: razor

As I'm still getting into Razor and JQuery, I'm wondering if it's possible to call your Javascript or JQuery functions from your inline razor script?

I ran into this question while trying to implement load spinners that were dependent on razor-level validation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> As I'm still getting into Razor and JQuery, I'm wondering if it's possible to call your Javascript or JQuery functions from your inline razor script?

Of course that it is possible. Razor is just a templating engine which translates to HTML. So you could do everything that you could do in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert($('div').html());
    });
</script>
<div>@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</div>
```

Comment: What about inside Razor functions?

`@functions
{
    private static List<string> GetFormErrors()
    {
        ....//call Javascript function from here.`

Comment: @Savage, razor functions run at the server side. What kind of javascript functions do you want to invoke?

Comment: As mentioned, the spinner.  I'm just getting my head around the Razor pipeline, and all I was really looking for was a bit of expert opinion to say you're out of your mind, or you're onto something :)

Comment: Where in the code example does it show javascript/jquery being called within a razor code block?